# Has anyone successfully limited the size of their WebView's cache?

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm creating a news reader app that, at times, loads web pages into a `WebView`.

I noticed that with default behavior, the cache can get very unreasonable very quickly.  Whether or not Android will clear out that cache when memory gets low, I'm not okay with my users seeing a 15MB news app when everything except the web cache is about 1MB.

However, I would love to use the cache to some extent.  I saw WebSettings#setAppCacheMaxSize() and it seemed like it was just the ticket.

It doesn't seem like it does anything.  I hardcoded the following into a method that is called by my activity's onCreate(), before anything is loaded:

`originalSourceWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(300*1024);` (I was using a larger, configurable value but dropped it lower to confirm my problem).

I blow right by 300KB without any fanfare, as shown by `settings->applications->manage applications->click on my app`.  I'm listening in WebChromeClient#onReachedAppMaxCacheSize for events, but that never seems to trigger.

Has anyone successfully used this?  Is there some different cache I should be trying to manage?  The docs seem pretty sparse.  I went into the android source but it just sends values off to native code, and I don't know how to delve into that.

My test environment is a nexus one on 2.2.2.  I know that I'll need to make the cache calls by reflection in order to support 1.5 and 1.6, but if I can't make this work, there will be no need.

Comment: I have tried so, cause I was curious. I tried tha method, passing 1024 and then 1, and it never seems to disptach the event, onReachedAppMaxCacheSize is never called. I'm using a Nexus 1 with 2.2.1. I can try on a HTC Desire and a Samsung Galaxy Tab with a feedback.

Comment: I have tested the same on a Samsung Galaxy Tab (originalSourceWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1);) and disptachs nothing at all. Is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's an API to do what you want.

`setAppCacheMaxSize` limits the cache size for the HTML5 application cache API -- the offline storage that HTML 5 apps can use while running in your WebView -- but it sounds like you want to limit the cache used for loading pages. images, etc.

As a workaround you could call `WebView.clearCache` periodically, although that really limits the effectiveness of the cache.  If you want to try and keep some recent pages around, you could look into getting them from `CacheManager` before clearing the cache and then restoring them afterwards.

Comment: I hit return on that first comment a little too quickly... then spent too long editing it.  What I meant to say is:  It makes sense that it would be limiting something else rather than being broken entirely.  A brief search of CacheManager suggests that it doesn't really appreciate being meddled with, but I might still try it.  Most likely I'll just clear the cache regularly instead.